# Find the flaw in this solution to IMO 1989 Problem 6

Tags: combinatorics, solution-verification, contest-math

Problem: Given all permutations of the set $\{1,2,\ldots,2n\}$, consider those  for which there exists an integer $i$ between $0$ and $2n$ such that $a_i-a_{i+1}$ ($a_k$ being the $k$-th term of the permutation) has an absolute value of $n$. Call all subsets with this property pleasant. Prove that there are more pleasant permutations than unpleasant permutations

Solution: Take any permutation. Let $a_1= k$ and $a_j$ is the smallest $j$ for which $a_j = k±n$. Then:

1.) Swap $a_{j-1}$ and $a_{j-2}$

2.) Swap $a_{j-2}$ with $a_1$

This supposedly creates a unique Pleasant permutation for every given unpleasant permutation, such a mapping being possible implies there are more pleasant permutation for every unpleasant permutation. The reason I think this is wrong, is because how straightforward this is(considering this is an IMO problem 6) and how I've never seen this solution anywhere online(correct me if wrong), which is why I think there's an obvious flaw

Edit: alright so, one thing is, for any non-P permutation, the sequence $a_{j-2}$, $a_{j-1}$, $a_{1}$, $a_j$  can be arranged like that or like $a_{j-2}$, $a_{j-1}$, $a_{j}$, $a_1$ giving two unique P-permutations for every non-P permutation, i.e 2/3 of all permutations atleast are P-permutations. Now one way to prove this solution wrong could be to work out a counterexample for n = 2, i.e that there aren't 2/3 × 4! = 2/3×24 = 16 P-permutations with just 4 numbers

Comment: Some IMO problems do have basically one-line solutions, that's not a disqualifying thing in and of itself. Either such a solution was missed by the problem committee, or they thought the solution was difficult enough to find. They are only human, and can make mistakes.

Comment: Can you check your indices? The first step doesn't seem to do anything useful and after the second step we have $\mid a_{j-2} - a_j\mid = k$ which is not what is required for a pleasent set.

Comment: And for next time, know that you can have dollar signs around an entire mathematical expression; you do not need to enclose each symbol in dollar signs. There is no need for `$a_i$ $-$ $a_{i+1}$`, you can just do `$a_i - a_{i+1}$`. It often looks better too.

Comment: @quarague $a_j$ $-$ $a_1$ = n. Basically insert $a_1$ between $a_j$ and $a_{j-1}$

Comment: @Arthur yeah but, how could the entire committee miss this, even if they somehow did it'd be a pretty popular blunder and this solution would be all over, say AOPS, while this problem wouldn't feature in any problem-books. But that's not the case.

Comment: I suspected you wanted to do something like insert $a_1$ between $a_j$ and $a_{j-1}$ but that is not what your description does. If you want to describe that with swaps, then it is swap $a_1$ and $a_2$, then swap $a_2$ and $a_3$, etc until finally swap $a_{j-2}$ and $a_{j-1}$.

Comment: No but, that's not what I wanted to do as that would remove the uniqueness of each mapping. $a_{k-1}$ swaps places with $a_{k-2}$, $a_1$ then swaps places with $a_{k-2}$, leaving everything in the middle unchanged

Comment: One also needs to show that every distinct bad permutation yields distinct good permutations under this transformation.

Comment: @QED we must prove that the set of non P-permutations is smaller than the set of P-permutations. We dont have to prove them equal.

Comment: No I meant If 2 bad non-P permutations yield the same $P$-permutation under this transformation then we have not proved that non-P permutations are in less numbers than $P$-permuations

Comment: @MNIShaurya, can you link your solution source?

Comment: @QED they dont. It's always a unique P-permutation from every non P-permutation

Comment: Yes I just checked that too.